# Errors when trying to build label_image neural net with bazel

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, bazel

Environment info

Operating System: El Capitan, 10.11.1

I'm doing this tutorial: https://petewarden.com/2016/09/27/tensorflow-for-mobile-poets/
Trying to classify images using tensorflow on iOS app.
When I try to build my net using bazel:
bazel build tensorflow/examples/label_image:label_image

I get these errors:
https://gist.github.com/galharth/36b8f6eeb12f847ab120b2642083a732

Answer (score 0):

From the related github issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6487 I think we narrowed it down to a lack of resources on the virtual machine. Bazel tends to get flakey with only 2GB of RAM allocated to it.